# Deleting Selected ListViewItems from the Database

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView` that I populate from the database.  The `ListView` has a `Checkbox` on each row which is a built-in property of `ListView`.

I have been trying to get the text from the ID column next to the `Checkbox` which I will use in deleting the respective rows from the database but it all fails. I thought I could get the `ListView.CheckedIndices` and use them in return to point to the `SelectedText` of each index.

However all fails. More specifically i wanted to use the `OnItemDeleting` Event of list view but the `ListView` I have does not seem to have such event.

Is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: can you please show your Listview - as a screenshot and what code you are implementing to achieve this functionality please ?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before. What I did was this below:

```
<asp:ListView ID="xyz" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="blah" OnClick="blah_Click" 
                        CommandArgument="<%# myObject.Id %>" /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I got the passed id through the command argument.Then I deleted the selected item and refreshed the data for `listView`. I am sure there must be a cleaner way of doing it.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion sir. But mine is in widows form.